# mysql query from Joomla table using timed publish via publish_up and publish_down

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

In my Joomla article table i've set the date, where an article should be published in column publish_up and the date, where an article should be hidden in the column publish_down.

The date format in these columns looks like this: 2023-10-30 23:05:13

How can I modify the followring mysql query, so that only articles get fetched that are publish on the actual day?

```
$mainQuery = "
            SELECT a.title, a.catid, a.modified, a.state , f . *
            FROM `huyr3_content` a
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT item_id as id, value as field_value, field_name 
                    FROM `huyr3_fields_values` v
                        INNER JOIN ( 
                            SELECT id, title as field_name 
                            FROM `huyr3_fields` n1) n2 
                        ON (n2.id = v.field_id)) f 
                    ON ( a.id = f.id )
            WHERE (a.state = 1 AND a.catid = 24)
            OR (a.state = 1 AND a.catid = 41)
            ORDER BY `title` ASC";
```

Comment: Do you mean articles where today's date is between the up and down dates? Try a BETWEEN clause in the sql

Comment: Not an issue but a simpler way to write `(a.state = 1 AND a.catid = 24) OR (a.state = 1 AND a.catid = 41)` could be `a.state = 1 AND a.catid in (24, 41)`

Comment: @Adyson: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Lets say there is an article with publish_up "2023-10-01 12:00:00" and publish_down "2023-11-01 12:00:00" I would like to only fetch it via msysql query if todays date is between 1.10. and 1.11.2023. 
Unfortunatly I'm very new to mysql syntax and I got the code I'm working with from another person.

Comment: You can find lots of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+between) to get you started. [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+current+datetime) will be useful too.